# Executing Shell Script from current directory without '"./filename"

Tags: linux, shell, admin

I have created a file called "testfile" and made it executable using `chmod +x testfile`.
In order to execute the file "testfile" i need to run the command `./testfile`.

I need to know is there any way i could run the program without using `./` and execute the file using `testfile` command?

Shown below is a simple code inside the file "testfile"

```
echo Todays date is : 
date
```

Comment: `export PATH=./:$PATH`, but this is not good.

Comment: Please don't call it `test` because that command already exists.

Comment: Why is it not advised to export . to the $PATH?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can execute it without ./ by using:

```
sh testfile
```

Or

```
sh /path/to/file/testfile
```

**Edit**
If you want to execute the program directly with a command, what you can do is to define an alias:

```
alias execute_testfile="sh /path/to/file/testfile"
```

And then, you will execute the program whenever you write

```
execute_testfile
```

or whatever name you define.

To make this alias persistent, do include the `alias ...` line in your ~/.profile or ~/.bash_profile files.

Comment: Yes, but i need execute my file without any of those. Like executing command which is already in linux. eg: top, ps, ls & etc.

Comment: Ah, right, in this case what you can do is to define an alias: `alias execute_testfile="sh /path/to/file/testfile"`. And then, whenever you write `execute_testfile` (or whatever name you define), you will execute the program.

Comment: Great, @frozenhaart! I edit my answer to include this explanation and further info. If it worked, you can mark question as answered.

Answer (score 4):

You can define PATH variable in .profile file which you can find under your home directory.

```
vi ~/.profile
```

Add to the end of your .profile

```
/path/to/dir/:$PATH
```

Which translates to "add /path/to/dir/ to whatever the PATH variable is set"

If you want to add a directory to the PATH for all users of the system you can:

```
vi /etc/environment - edit, save your changes
source /etc/environment
echo $PATH - should now return your new PATH
```

Works on Ubuntu server, I would guess on all Debian distributions, I am not sure if other distributions have /etc/environment or if PATH is specified somewhere else

Aliasing is still a better solution

```
vi ~/.bashrc
```

Add to the end of the file

```
alias <your_script> ='/path/to/your_script.sh'
```

Log out, log back in - you shouldnt have to type ./.sh anymore'

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `.` to your `PATH` variable like this:

```
> echo 'echo Hello, World!' > mycommand
> mycommand
-bash: mycommand: command not found
> ./mycommand
Hello, World!
> PATH=".:$PATH";
> mycommand
Hello, World!
>
```

Comment: Thanks for the Reply, but where do i add this - `PATH=".:$PATH";`

Comment: @frozenhaart Do thin in shell prompt before running your command.  Added more details to the answer.